# Database account password expiry identification

Tags: linux, database, oracle, shell, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to check on database account password status on a daily basis and send an email of acounts that have password expiry in the next two weeks??

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `dba_users` view `EXPIRY_DATE` column to check when password will be expired.

For your case, You can use the following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    DBA_USERS
WHERE
    EXPIRY_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE AND SYSDATE + 14
    AND ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'OPEN'; -- change this according to your requirement
```

Comment: I couldn't find dba_users table. So is there any other way to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I can share a package I use; huh, now I see that it was written while there was no `LISTAGG` yet so - feel free to fix that, if you want.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_sys
AS
   PROCEDURE p_users_to_expire
   AS
      l_users_to_expire   VARCHAR2 (300);
   BEGIN
      SELECT RTRIM (
                XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (
                           e,
                              u.username
                           || ' '
                           || TO_CHAR (u.expiry_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
                           || CHR (13)) ORDER BY u.username).EXTRACT (
                   '//text()'),
                CHR (13))
        INTO l_users_to_expire
        FROM dba_users u
       WHERE     TRUNC (u.expiry_date) > SYSDATE
             AND TRUNC (u.expiry_date) - TRUNC (SYSDATE) < 14;       --> 2 weeks

      IF l_users_to_expire IS NOT NULL
      THEN
         for cur_r in (select 'littlefoot@xyz.com' recipient from dual union all 
                       select 'bigfoot@xyz.com' recipient from dual
                      )
         loop                      
         pkg_sys.p_send_mail (
            par_from        => 'dba@xyz.com',
            par_recipient   => cur_r.recipient,
            par_subject     => 'Users to expire',
            par_mail_host   => NULL,
            par_msg_text    => l_users_to_expire);
         end loop;            
      END IF;
   END p_users_to_expire;


   PROCEDURE p_send_mail (par_from        IN VARCHAR2,
                          par_recipient   IN VARCHAR2,
                          par_subject     IN VARCHAR2,
                          par_mail_host   IN VARCHAR2,
                          par_msg_text    IN VARCHAR2)
   AS
      v_Mail_Host   VARCHAR2 (30) := NVL (par_mail_host, 'mail.xyz.com');
      v_Mail_Conn   UTL_SMTP.Connection;
      crlf          VARCHAR2 (2) := CHR (13) || CHR (10);
   BEGIN
      v_Mail_Conn := UTL_SMTP.Open_Connection (v_Mail_Host, 25);
      UTL_SMTP.Helo (v_Mail_Conn, v_Mail_Host);
      UTL_SMTP.Mail (v_Mail_Conn, par_From);
      UTL_SMTP.Rcpt (v_Mail_Conn, par_Recipient);
      UTL_SMTP.Data (
         v_Mail_Conn,
            'Date: '
         || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
         || crlf
         || 'From: '
         || par_From
         || crlf
         || 'Subject: '
         || par_Subject
         || crlf
         || 'To: '
         || par_Recipient
         -- 2 CRLFs
         || crlf
         || crlf
         -- message text
         || par_msg_text
         || crlf);
      UTL_SMTP.Quit (v_mail_conn);
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN UTL_SMTP.Transient_Error OR UTL_SMTP.Permanent_Error
      THEN
         raise_application_error (-20000, 'Unable to send mail: ' || SQLERRM);
   END p_send_mail;
END pkg_sys;
/
```